# Java IO Create / Append File

Tags: java, file, file-io

Im trying to create a file if it doesnt exist, if it does exist append to it. 
Is this the best way to do it? Im not sure having two try catches inside one method is good personally?

```
   public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String fileLocation = "/temp/";
        String name = "Bob";
        String timeStamp = "1988-03-15";
        Path path = Paths.get(fileLocation+ "info.log");

        if(!Files.exists(path)){
            try {
                Files.createFile(path);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
            SimpleDateFormat tTimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");
            writer.write(tTimeFormatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + " name: " + name + " Timestamp: "+ timeStamp);
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.print(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: What is the best way to check if a file exists, create it if not, append to the file if it does.

Comment: You have a logical problem here, if the file does not exist and creation fails, it would still attempt to write to file, thus causing another exception.

Comment: Good spot thanks - although I think with @eg04lt3r solution it prevents that happening now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write to file with StandardOpenOptions: CREATE and APPEND.

```
Files.write(Paths.get(""), new byte[] {}, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

CREATE - means if file doesn't exists it creates new one otherwise get existing.
APPEND - means append new data to existing content in file.

So, you can do all your operations with a single line.

Comment: Ohh Excellent - I didn't know I could put in multiple options, Create and Append together both worked.

Comment: Yeah, and it's better to use Files class for manipulations with files.

Comment: Separately if I wanted a new line id need to do Files.write(path, "new line", option);

Comment: Yes, you can check others "write" methods of Files class and use them if you need.

Answer (score 1):

The File.createNewFile() method creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. This methods return a true value if the file is created successfully and false if the file already exists or the operation failed.

```
if (myFile.createNewFile()){
    System.out.println("File is created!");
   }else{
    System.out.println("File already exists.");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the printWriter class like this

```
java.io.PrintWriter p = new java.io.PrintWriter(yourFileHere);
// You can use println to print a new line if it allready exists
p.println(yourTextHere);
// Or append to the end of the file
p.append("TEXT HERE!!!!")
```